# How to force grouping of monadic verbs?

Tags: j

I came up with an incorrect J verb in my head, which would find the proportion of redundant letters in a string.  I started with just a bunch of verbs with no precedence defined, and tried grouping inwards:

```
   c=. 'cool' NB. The test data string, 1/4 is redundant.
   box =. 5!:2 NB. The verb to show the structure of another verb in a box.
   p=.%#~.%# NB. First attempt. Meant to read "inverse of (tally of unique divided by tally)".
   box < 'p'
┌─┬─┬────────┐
│%│#│┌──┬─┬─┐│
│ │ ││~.│%│#││
│ │ │└──┴─┴─┘│
└─┴─┴────────┘
   p2=.%(#~.%#) NB. The first tally is meant to be in there with the nub sieve, so paren everything after the inverse monad.
   box < 'p2'
┌─┬────────────┐
│%│┌─┬────────┐│
│ ││#│┌──┬─┬─┐││
│ ││ ││~.│%│#│││
│ ││ │└──┴─┴─┘││
│ │└─┴────────┘│
└─┴────────────┘
   p3=. %((#~.)%#) NB. The first tally is still not grouped with the nub sieve, so paren the two together directly. 
   box < 'p3'
┌─┬────────────┐
│%│┌──────┬─┬─┐│
│ ││┌─┬──┐│%│#││
│ │││#│~.││ │ ││
│ ││└─┴──┘│ │ ││
│ │└──────┴─┴─┘│
└─┴────────────┘
   p3 c  NB. Looks about right, so test it!
|length error: p3
|       p3 c
   (#~.)c  NB. Unexpected error, but I guessed as to what part had the problem.
|length error
|       (#~.)c
```

My question is, why did my approach to grouping fail with this length error, and how should I have grouped it to get the desired effect?
(I assume it is something to do with turning it into a hook instead of grouping, or it just not realising it needs to use the monad forms, but I don't know how to verify or get around it if so.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fork](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/fork) and [compose](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/ampv).

`(# ~.)` is a [hook](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/hook). This is probably what you're not expecting. `(# ~.) 'cool'` is applying `~.` to `'cool'` to give you `'col'`. But as it's a monadic hook, it is then attempting `'cool' # 'col'`, which isn't what you're intending and which gives a length error.

To get `0.25` as the ratio of redundant characters in a string, don't use the reciprocal (`%`). You just subtract from 1 the ratio of unique characters. This is pretty straightforward with a fork:

```
   (1 - #&~. % #) 'cool'
0.25
   p9 =. 1 - #&~. % #
   box < 'p9'
┌─┬─┬──────────────┐
│1│-│┌────────┬─┬─┐│
│ │ ││┌─┬─┬──┐│%│#││
│ │ │││#│&│~.││ │ ││
│ │ ││└─┴─┴──┘│ │ ││
│ │ │└────────┴─┴─┘│
└─┴─┴──────────────┘
```

Compose (`&`) ensures that you tally (`#`) the nub (`~.`) together, so that the fork grabs it as a single verb. The fork is a series of three verbs that applies the first and third verb, and then applies the middle verb to the results. So `#&~. % #` is the fork, where `#&~.` is applied to the string, resulting in `3`. `#` is applied, resulting in `4`. And then `%` is applied to those results, as `3 % 4`, giving you `0.75`. That's our ratio of unique characters.

`1 -` is just to get us `0.25` instead of `0.75`. `% 0.75` is the same as `1 % 0.75`, which gives you `1.33333`.

Comment: I usually use @ instead of & when working with monadic verbs because they have the same effect and that leaves & for binding nouns to verbs. I did use & in a dyadic way through a hook in this solution though.        -.@(%~&# ~.)'cool'
 and the use of the -. instead of 1-

Comment: I should have realised I needed complement rather than inverse.  Apart from that, your solution, Dane, is a loyal translation of my original thinking: 1-#&~.%# could be read "one minus tally of unique divided by tally".

And @bob, I believe your solution ~.@(%~&#~.) could be read: "complement of division of tallies of non-unique and unique". 

Do I understand correctly on both counts?

Comment: For my part your interpretation is correct. I also realized that last night you could have an answer that is closer to a fractional format than decimal float by applying the x: verb to the result.    x:@ -.@(%~&# ~.)'cool' results in 1r4 which is the rational expression in J for 0.25  Hope this is helpful.